# Create Json from Raw Data from WSS Symantec?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x, filter

I need filter strings data from Symantec WSS,
I got only values without keys.
So I think for myself try action and split every space.

Example of Raw Data:

```
9777 10/30/2019 08:10:10 192.168.1.2 "Virus Found" Scott Sampson
```

I want result of JSON:

```
{
"pid":"9777",
"timestamp":"10/30/2019 08:10:10",
"ip":"192.168.1.2",
"message":"Virus Found",
"first_name":"Scott",
"first_name":"Sampson"
}
```

I started my code, but I stuck:

```
data = r'''9777 10/30/2019 08:10:10 192.168.1.2 "Virus Found" Scott Sampson'''
ls1 = []
text = ""
for x in data:
    if x is '"':
        ls1.append('"')
    else:
        ls1.append(x)
print(ls1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression. Using named groups you can directly get a dictionary from the match object.

```py
import json
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    r'(?P<pid>\d+)\s(?P<timestamp>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?P<ip>(?:\d+\.?)+)\s\"(?P<message>('
    r'?:\w+\s?)+)\"\s(?P<first_name>\w+)\s(?P<last_name>\w+)')
match = pattern.match(r'''9777 10/30/2019 08:10:10 192.168.1.2 "Virus Found" Scott Sampson''')
print(json.dumps(match.groupdict()))
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/982gIh/1)